# Method is not defined

Tags: python

I'm new to programming and attempting to write different versions of the DiceRoller game in Python.

My code is as follows and I get a `doAgain is not defined` error.

I'm not sure if this is something simple like indenting, or I need to put a break somewhere.

I know this is probably a duplicate, but I'm still having a little trouble finding this exact issue.

```
import random
min = 1
max = 6

roll_again = 'yes'

while roll_again == 'yes' or roll_again == 'y':
    print 'Rolling the dice...'
    print 'The values are...'
    print random.randint(min,max)
    print random.randint(min,max)
    doAgain()

def doAgain():
    userInput = raw_input('\nWould you like to roll the dice again? \nYes \nNo')

    if userInput == 'Yes':
        roll_again
    elif userInput == 'No':
        print ('Thank you for playing!')
    else:
        print ('You have entered an incorrect response.')
```

Comment: Put `doAgain()` function before `while` loop.

Comment: Not your current issue, but note that roll_again never gets updated and so your loop will continue forever.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define `doAgain()` before you call it. Move `def doAgain():` above the `while` loop.

Comment: EIther, you can separate the `while` loop into another function, then you can keep the order. The interpreter will look for the names only when that function will be called.

Answer (score 0):

In your current setup `def doAgain` is defined after you are calling it. So it does not know `doAgain()` yet. The answer from John is correct as he said. I do want to add that if you put things in a class, you can put the definition also below the point where you call it.

For example:

```
class HelloWorld():
    # This definition automaticly get executed when the the class is executed. 
    def __init__(self):
        print('Starting.....')
        self.sayIt()

    def sayIt(self):
        print('Hello World')

# Run class 
HelloWorld()
```

Comment: Defining a class for this is overkill. You could just as easily define a function which contains the while loop, then call that function.